# Using $if or $ifNull condition inside a $match that will be executed in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, jasper-reports

```
{
$match: { 
$expr: {
$or: [
{$ifNull : [$P{departmentuid},"warduid":{"$eq": {"$oid":$P{warduids} } } ] },
{$ifNull : [$P{warduids},"orderdepartmentuid": {"$eq": {"$oid":$P{departmentuid} } } ] }
]
}
}
},
```

I am trying to create a query that will be executed from Jaspersoft Studio. Now, the parameter that will be sent to the query is either of the two set parameters, so I created a $match that has a condition that it will only filter one parameter that will be received.
I am not quite sure if im doing the right query for this. Hope someone can help. Thanks!

The parameters that will be recieved from jaspersoft studio is either **$P{departmentuid}** or **${warduids}**

The logic will just be, If the query recieved $P{departmentuid} parameter, It will apply departmentuid only in the whole query but if it received $P{warduid} it will apply warduid only.

Comment: $ifNull is not flow control.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815970/mongo-db-conditional-query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when `$P{departmentuid}` or `${warduids}`, they will be supplemented the value of **null**.

You could then do the followings:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $and: [
              {$eq: [null, $P{warduids}]},
              {$eq: ["$orderdepartmentuid", $P{departmentuid}]}
            ]
          },
          {
            $and: [
              {$eq: [null, $P{departmentuid}]},
              {$eq: ["$warduid", $P{warduids}]}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pt2Yh9YnHAn) when `$P{warduids}` is null.

And here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZIUWfblhFD4) when `$P{departmentuid}` is null