# Can I write a Mongo/Mongoose .find({ $or[...] }) query that conditionally includes/excludes members of the $or[] array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to write a query that accepts two search parameters; `search` and `category`. I want it to return records where `productModel.name` or `productModel.description` include `search` or where `productModel.category` includes `category`.

This works but it breaks if either the `search` or `category` argument is not present.

```
return this.productModel.find({
  $or: [
    { name: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } },
    { description: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } },
    { category: { $regex: category, $options: 'i' } },
  ],
});
```

I got around it by writing three separate queries to be run conditionally but I would like to be able to do the whole thing in one query if possible.

```
if (!category) {
  return this.productModel.find({
    $or: [
      { name: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } },
      { description: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } },
    ],
  });
}

if (!search) {
  return this.productModel.find({
    category: { $regex: category, $options: 'i' },
  });
}

return this.productModel.find({
  $or: [
    { name: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } },
    { description: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } },
    { category: { $regex: category, $options: 'i' } },
  ],
});
```

Is there an elegant way of handling the conditional presence of these two parameters within a single Mongo query?

Comment: use `||` like  `{ name: { $regex: search || '', $options: 'i' } }` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo db conditional query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815970/mongo-db-conditional-query)

Comment: @ray Yeah - that's pretty much it - thanks; I managed to put something together based on that, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

mongoose query builder can do this. The query is returned by `Model.find()` method.

I will use [Query.prototype.or()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.or()) helper function to demonstrate. When the query builder is created, call [Query.prototype.exec()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.exec()) to execute the query.

Besides, we can use [Query.prototype.getQuery()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.getQuery()) to check the query filter.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import util from 'util';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
interface Product {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  category: string;
}
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema<Product>({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  category: String
});
const Product = mongoose.model<Product>('product', productSchema);

(async function main() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);

    // seed
    await Product.create(
      [
        { name: 'apple', description: 'best apple', category: 'a' },
        { name: 'banana', description: 'best banana', category: 'a' },
        { name: 'PS5', description: 'Play Station 5', category: 'b' }
      ]
    )

    const search = 'apple'
    const description = ''
    const category = 'b'

    const query = Product.find();
    search && query.or([{ name: { '$regex': search, '$options': 'i' } }])
    description && query.or([{ description: { '$regex': description, '$options': 'i' } }])
    category && query.or([{ category: { '$regex': category, '$options': 'i' } }])

    console.log('query: ', util.inspect(query.getQuery(), false, null))

    const docs = await query.exec();
    console.log('docs: ', docs);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    await Promise.all(['products'].map(c => mongoose.connection.dropCollection(c)))
    await mongoose.connection.close()
  }
})();
```

Logs:

```bash
Mongoose: products.insertOne({ name: 'apple', description: 'best apple', category: 'a', _id: ObjectId("6470704481ac7a00ecebb54b"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: products.insertOne({ name: 'banana', description: 'best banana', category: 'a', _id: ObjectId("6470704481ac7a00ecebb54c"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: products.insertOne({ name: 'PS5', description: 'Play Station 5', category: 'b', _id: ObjectId("6470704481ac7a00ecebb54d"), __v: 0}, {})
query:  {
  '$or': [
    { name: { '$regex': 'apple', '$options': 'i' } },
    { category: { '$regex': 'b', '$options': 'i' } }
  ]
}
Mongoose: products.find({ '$or': [ { name: { '$regex': 'apple', '$options': 'i' } }, { category: { '$regex': 'b', '$options': 'i' } } ]}, {})
docs:  [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6470704481ac7a00ecebb54d"),
    name: 'PS5',
    description: 'Play Station 5',
    category: 'b',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6470704481ac7a00ecebb54b"),
    name: 'apple',
    description: 'best apple',
    category: 'a',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

package version: `"mongoose": "^7.2.1"`